# Is the order of a saved BQ query permanent?

Tags: google-bigquery

If a `SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY row ASC` query is executed and then saved to table2 (table1 is regularly updated, and each time it is, table2 is to be replaced by this query), is the order of table2 guaranteed to be respected by bigqeury? Seeing as the data is overwritten, and not just appended to, I would assume it would be free from the effects of the periodic coalesce operation. If the order is guaranteed, can I also be sure that when I, or anyone else, access this data using tabledata:list, that the data will be returned in the order it was saved in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a table is created in a single operation, the order of access should be stable. Note though that response size limits apply when you are selecting from one table into another. You might be better off copying the table, which is a fast snapshot operation that also does a form of coalesce (it also doesn't incur any charges for the copy operation, unlike a query). As long as you recreated it every couple of days, it would be immune from coalesce.

Comment: I thought that you could do an asynchronous job with a destinationTable, and that all the results would be saved to it? Does the copy operation respect row order?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if I gave you some more specific info on my situation - a list of possible solutions I've looked at is here https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=221055.msg2347579#msg2347579 maybe you could tell me which, if any, is possible, or which may be possible soon?

Comment: Copy does respect row ordering.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! My very last question - If I create a table (either by copying or by creating it in a single operation from a query), now I repeat this using WRITE_TRUNCATE, will coalesce be suppressed or do I need to delete the table first before recreating it?

Comment: WRITE_TRUNCATE should be sufficient.